# Redirect the Oracle query output to a file without using spool

Tags: sql, oracle, file, redirect, output

We would like to generate/redirect a sql query output to a Linux file.
We do not have access to SQLPLUS on production systems.
The script will go in Apps server code.
Please help.

Regards

Comment: What are you using to run the query?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need some command that allows you to execute the query. If you don't have access to any such command, and can't copy sqlplus over (because it just needs too much of the client installed to work), the best idea i'd have is write a java program that either takes the query from the command line or has a few fixed queries built in, and that allows you to specify a file to write the output to. If you pack this program together with the thin client, you end up with one .jar file that doesn't rely on anything else - except a jre, which is more or less ubiquitous on today's server systems.